# visual studio code error- string cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, arrays, string, variables

hi there I need help with my visual studio code.
I want to know why I can not create a new string variable on my visual studio code ?!!
I am getting this error>> **string cannot be resolved to a type**

[image: click to see the image of the error]

Comment: capitalize String

Comment: It's `String` like 2 rows above in the main definition

Comment: i am now getting this error >>The local variable ans may not have been initialized
for the string variable ans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They keyword in Java is `String`.

Comment: Don't answer to such typo, thanks to delete

Comment: i am now getting this error >>The local variable ans may not have been initialized for the string variable "ans" !

Comment: You haven't given the variable an initial value, which you should do when declaring it within a method. So you could just set it to an empty string.